# Outlook - automatically move, file, add attachments to latest conversation email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm new to this website so my apologies for lack of knowledge of this website as well as Outlook in general.

I'm hoping someone is able to help me please... apologies again but this is a long one...

I have Windows 10 and (I think!) the latest Outlook.
In my work, many emails come in to the inbox with differing subject titles, I have already set up a rule that any email with the word 'query' is moved to my query folder which for me is a great start.

1, Some conversations mean I could have 20/30 emails in each query conversation, I've been manually moving the older emails (which have automatically moved to my 'query' folder) from each conversation to my archive folder, so I only keep the latest email, meaning my folder is updated.

Do you know if there is anything I can set up that automatically moves the older emails to my 'closed' folder please?

2, Also, in the chain of emails, quite often I send attachments, quite often, the customer will hit reply but not add the attachment. As I'm moving the older emails to an archive folder, the attachment either gets lost in there, or, what I have been doing which is time consuming is manually editting the final email in the query chain to add the attachment. 
Does anyone know if there is a way of automatically adding all of the attachments to the final email to ensure they are all noted in one email?

3, Finally, once a query is completed, the customer then often makes an order, the way I receive an order is the subject changes from 'query' to 'order' and a few details on the subject remain the same as the query conversation but not always. 
It can then be difficult to sometimes pair the two emails (the final email from the query conversation and the order email). 
In an ideal world, I'd like the order email and the query email linking so I have everything there I need... Does anyone know if there's a way to do this rather than trying to play Pairs?

Thank you so much for your patience if you've read all of that and hope it makes sense, and thank you in advance to everyone who may be able to help me save quite a bit of time in my day.

Answer (score 0):

Re Q1: Outlook provides a "Conversation Clean Up" feature, which could automatically evaluate the contents of each message in the Conversation. If a message is completely contained within one of the replies, the previous message is deleted. Outlook deletes earlier messages that have duplicate content but will not delete messages with attachments. You can also configure which folder to go for these cleaned-up items. See this article for more details:

[Use Conversation Clean Up to delete redundant messages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-conversation-clean-up-to-delete-redundant-messages-70179d54-fa57-48ce-95fd-416d72e5ccd4)

Regarding Q2 & Q3, I'm afraid Outlook doesn't provide build-in options to achieve these. You may wait and see whether others have any suggestion on this. Maybe it's possible via codes.